# Book where young people around the world are chosen to go to the moon

Tags: story-identification, books, moon

I have a vague memory of reading a book where young people around the world are chosen to go to the moon (I guess like Charlie and the Chocolate Factory or a competition or something along those line). While I don't really remember much else, all I know is they got to the moon where there was a sort of moon base, where the people invited with their accompanying relatives live. I know it's vague but I'm not getting much else from my memory.

Comment: In Heinlein's 'Have Spacesuit, will travel' there's a competition to win a trip to the Moon.

Answer (score 6):

It could be Arthur C. Clarke's *[Islands in the Sky](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/56726.Islands_in_the_Sky)*.

**young people around the world are chosen to go to the moon (I guess like Charlie and the Chocolate Factory or a competition or something along those line).**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islands_in_the_Sky):

> At age sixteen, Roy Malcolm has made himself an expert in the history of aviation, so much so that he wins the Aviation Quiz Program, presented on television by World Airways, Inc. Because the prize was described as an all expenses paid trip to “any part of the earth” (rather than on Earth), Roy is able to request a trip to the Inner Station, which is considered part of Earth because its orbit lies under the one-thousand-kilometer limit of earth’s legal territory.

While on the station, he goes to glasses and activities with several cadets his age, and takes part on several missions with them. Later in the book, they go on a rocket trip which makes a pit stop on the moon.

Comment: Good thought. They only orbit the moon though, and that by accident.

Comment: The story involves multiple young people from around the world, as well as some of their accompanying relatives. If I remember correctly, they weren't actually aware that what they won was a trip to space, I believe it was actually winning a trip to a new amusement park that no one has ever gone to, where one of the rides was going to this moon base, the main ride rather.